# How do I make EF Core 7 query with multiple navigations/levels efficient with AutoMapping to Dto?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, automapper, ef-core-7.0

I'm using EF Core 7 for the first time with the context of an endpoint in an ASP.NET Core Web API project.

I have a table of `Venue`s and I am attempting to:

- Query them
- Pipe them through AutoMapper to a Dto/public model
- Return them (serialized by framework)

**The problem** is that this is extremely slow when `.UseLazyLoadingProxies()` is used, presumable because AutoMapper is accessing each of the properties for each of the Venue's in the `Queryable` and this fires individual nav queries.

**I've tried** to emit this and add `.Entity<Venue>().Navigation(x => x.Location).AutoInclude();` to configuration. However, this is not the only property, and I'm going to have to do this for all of them. This is also not particularly maintainable; as it'd be too easy to miss this configuration when adding a new navigable and the performance impact may not easily be noticed.

Is there a way to frontload in a maintainable manor all navigation properties (and it's navigation properties) for a model for a query I know that'll need it?

Query site:

```cs
using var db = new VenuesContext(Fetch.Lazy);
var query = db.Venues.AsQueryable();

if (manager != null)
    query = query.Where(v => v.Managers.Contains(manager));

if (dataCenter != null)
    query = query.Where(v => v.Location.DataCenter.ToLower() == dataCenter.ToLower());

if (world != null)
    query = query.Where(v => v.Location.World.ToLower() == world.ToLower());

var complexFiltered = query.AsEnumerable().Where(c => /* alt source ACLs filter */);
var mapped = complexFiltered.Select(this._modelMapper.Map<Venue>);

return mapped;
```

Venue model:

```cs
[Table("Venues", Schema = nameof(Entities.Venues))]
public class Venue : IEntity, ISecurityScoped
{
    [Key] 
    public string Id { get; init; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Added { get; set; }

    public virtual Location Location { get; set; } = new ();
    public Uri Website { get; set; }

    [DeleteBehavior(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)] 
    public virtual List<Opening> Openings { get; set; } = new ();
    public virtual List<string> Managers { get; set; } = new ();    
}
```

My `DbContext`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("Venues");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Venue>().Navigation(x => x.Location).AutoInclude();
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Meow");
    if (_fetchKind == Fetch.Lazy)
        optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
}
```

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html

Comment: Yeah, utilize AM `ProjectTo` - it does not need `Include`, tracking, proxies etc., everything is `Select`-ed directly into your DTOs.

Comment: I did have a play around with that, though it seems to struggle if there's a property that mapped by calculation. I'm taking another look. I'm curious if there is another option however as this means the query has to go directly to Dto at enumeration - there is no opportunity to do in-memory LINQ before projection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is tripping you up is whatever is justifying this code:

.Where(c => /* alt source ACLs filter */)

If you can work that out to continue to work as `IQueryable` then Automapper's `ProjectTo` will be able to handle the mapping expression in SQL and you can remove any/all eager loading and not have the cost of lazy load hits. Otherwise you will need to ensure *all* navigation properties that will be touched by Automapper to build the destination class are eager loaded. This is less ideal because it means you are coupling the mapping configuration to each and every query that might use it (The mapping requires certain navigation properties to be eager loaded or it results in expensive lazy load calls) and this can in turn produce expensive Cartesian Products through the JOINs. You can mitigate some of the JOIN expense using `.AsSplitQuery()` before the `AsEnumerable()`. This will have the EF DbContext execute separate queries to retrieve the related entities, mitigating the Cartesian Product of a single query. However this still results in all of those related entities being loaded and tracked by the DbContext to be available when the mapper.Map() call is to sift through them.

The best thing is to do whatever possible to remove the `.AsEnumerable()' even if the resulting expressions look "messy", as long as it can be fed to SQL and understood/correct, the resulting query will be many factors faster and less resource costly than the alternative.

Comment: I'm starting to come to this conclusion, but it is kinda perplexing me. Doesn't this mean that (what I thought would be) a pretty standard combination of EF Core and Mapping is limited to using domain objects only for SQL-understandable querying? No manipulating or even using domain-model specifical properties? Unless DTO generation always has it's own query, and I do a second unmapped clone of the query for using the domain-objects unique properties?

Comment: EF entities serve the domain where DTOs or ViewModels serve the consumers. Projection applies to converting domain entities into the DTO/ViewModel, and Automapper's Map(src, dest) can assist with basic scenarios where you want to copy values back after re-loading the entity and dealing with concurrency concerns. For things like formatting and translation, I keep these in ViewModels. Worst case if it's clumsy to translate via mapping then load raw values into the VM and then the VM can expose additional properties for formatting.

Comment: Heya, thank for taking the time to answer my comment ♥. 
I understand the responsibility between domain/dto's, my issue is more that if I want DTOs there's no opportunity for in-memory operations on the domain models before getting DTOs. Unless I go the Include option.

Comment: (Regardless of my above pondering; I this is the correct answer so I've marked it so)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen colleagues recently suggested using AutoMapper. Please consider using the [Mapster](https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster) library instead of AutoMapper as it is faster and consumes less memory. Your problem can be solved with the [ProjectToType](https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster/blob/master/src/Mapster.EFCore/TypeAdapterBuilderExtensions.cs#L83) extension method.

You can also look at the query itself: as far as I can see, it uses the `.Contains` method and some comparisons in the `Where` predicates. This can be a source of performance issues, as such lookups may require sub-optimal sequential table scans.